# How to remove soft close drawer slide (no levers)?

Tags: drawers

This heavy duty drawer slide is from a kitchen cabinet and I can't figure out how to release it from the cupboard. I tried taking off the bottom screws, but it still won't come off. There must be a release mechanism, but I can't seem to find it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The grey item in second picture, try pulling, pushing, moving it left/right /to the front or back the little lever coming out the back of it.

Comment: Put the screws back immediately. Then figure out how to manipulate the levers to release the drawer. AFIK all types of these drawers can be released without tools.

Comment: Agree w/Gunner - that grey lever really looks like it needs to move to the left (from the perspective of that picture). There's probably a matching one on the other side of the drawer and they probably both need to move at the same time (or at least both be moved before the drawer can be removed).

Comment: I see a lever on the back right of the top photo. Tilt this up and the slide won't stop there, there is probably one on each side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all you need to do is lift the drawer up when it's at full extension. It takes a bit of force. To put it back in, you just slide it in. Here's a video I found:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-B0Nym9vp0s

Answer (score 1):

Those appear to be IKEA drawers,  there is little tab that must be pressed while pulling the drawer out. It is a little white tab, you can see it in a slot cut into the metal of the slide just a little in back of the grey plastic piece. You need to push up in it with a small screwdriver or anything small enough to fit in the slot.

A [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYWEjmkzX4s) will do better at explaining this.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RooJ5qk95cg) that explains the adjustment screws you see in your photos, they adjust the drawer fronts.

Comment: Unfortunately not, see my answer below